# CFURLDestroyResource is now deprecated in iOS7. What to use instead?

Tags: ios7, deprecated

CFURLDestroyResource is now deprecated.  I am unsure what to use instead of it though, and haven't had any luck digging through Apple's documentation.

I am using BlackRaccoon to manipulate my FTP server and it makes use of CFURLDestroyResource which is of course now causing a compiler warning.

Comment: This should not be hard to run down, but I simply can't find anything on it...frustrating.

Comment: I checked into Gold Raccoon also, and it too makes use of this same function, so I am still stuck on this one.

Comment: You will find most of the Raccoons are ports of Black Raccoon. Unfortunately, Apple appears to be removing FTP functionality which is problematic. Personally, I would recommend a full-featured FTP library that doesn't depend on Apples functions. You will be better off in the future. As far as I can tell, there is no substitute for CFURLDestroyResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also ran into this issue and couldn't find any alternative within Apple's framework; in CFURLAccess.h, Apple recommends using NSURLConnection, but I could not find a way to perform deletions with said class.  It would also seem that most third-party libraries make use of CFURLDestroyResource as well.

Then we unearthed this:  https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager.  This FTPManager leverages the fact that Objective-C is a strict superset of C and performs the FTP operations by creating the raw sockets and simply writing the commands manually.  It is a method that may be a bit "nuts and bolts" for developers who are accustomed to high-level solutions, but it's elegant in its minimalism and efficiency.  And when you get right down to it, most other FTP frameworks are probably executing commands such as these at some level anyway.